# How to pass value for python for loop?

Tags: python

In C/C++:

```
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
```

In Python:

```
for i in range(0,5)
```

Question is:

```
s=[1,2,3,4,1]

for i in s:
    for j in s:
```

Here i wanna make second for loop j=1 (j value should be start with 1 like this s[1]=2).How do i pass that value.

Comment: I guess this should be answered on SO.

Comment: For the questions on programming go for http://stackoverflow.com .. You will really get good help their .. that too in very short time .. You may get to know many more things than your expectation ..

Comment: I have voted you up (to 20) .. Now .. Accept the answer which you think helped ..

Answer (score 1):

You should ask this on stackoverflow, but the answer is (if I got you right):

```
for i in s:
   for j in s[1:]:
```

Read this chapter about [lists in python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html), this will help you.

Comment: If the solution helps you, select the checkmark beside this answer.